# Overlay 2 divs with one div (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have 2 sections in my View.

Here is code of View:

```html
<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2>About Grayscale</h2>
            <p>
               
            </p>
            <p>
              
            </p>
            <p>Н</p>
        </div>
       
</section>
<!-- Download Section -->
<section id="download" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="download-section"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">Программа обучения VR</h2>
               <div style="width:30%;height:530px;float:left;border-style:solid;border-width:15px;border-color:#42DCA3">
                   <p style="padding-top:10px;font-size:30px;"><b>VR</b></p>
                   <p style="color:#FFD700;font-size:35px;"><b><strike>3600  грн </strike></b></p>
                   <p style="color:black;font-size:28px;"><b>2600  грн до 24.06.17 </b></p>
                   <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #42DCA3;border-top: 1px solid #42DCA3;padding: 20px 0;margin-bottom: 20px;font-size:20px;">
                         6 недель, 12 занятий,36 часов<br>
                         + практика с HTC Vive<br>
                         + создание 3D объектов<br>
                         + создание ролика с камерой 360°
                   </div>
                   <div style="font-size:20px;">Старт 01.07.17</div>
                   <div style="margin: 0 auto;padding-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Оставить заявку</button>
                </div>
               </div>
              
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[Here is all code with css](https://codepen.io/suhomlineugene/pen/WOGoPV)**

I need to create block that overlay this 2 divs like here in design

[image]

How I can do this?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have price block properly positioned on the left side, it should be the first element (see snippet below).
Not sure what you mean by overlaying as this can be achieved by using image and dark colour as DIV's background so no actual overlay is needed.

If you however need to overlay divs then you can use position absolute to do it or use flex boxes.

```html
<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2>About Grayscale</h2>
            <p>
               
            </p>
            <p>
              
            </p>
            <p>Н</p>
        </div>
       
</section>
<!-- Download Section -->
<section id="download" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="download-section"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                
               <div style="width:30%;height:530px;float:left;border-style:solid;border-width:15px;border-color:#42DCA3; margin-right: 20px">
                   <p style="padding-top:10px;font-size:30px;"><b>VR</b></p>
                   <p style="color:#FFD700;font-size:35px;"><b><strike>3600  грн </strike></b></p>
                   <p style="color:black;font-size:28px;"><b>2600  грн до 24.06.17 </b></p>
                   <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #42DCA3;border-top: 1px solid #42DCA3;padding: 20px 0;margin-bottom: 20px;font-size:20px;">
                         6 недель, 12 занятий,36 часов<br>
                         + практика с HTC Vive<br>
                         + создание 3D объектов<br>
                         + создание ролика с камерой 360°
                   </div>
                   <div style="font-size:20px;">Старт 01.07.17</div>
                   <div style="margin: 0 auto;padding-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Оставить заявку</button>
                </div>
               </div>
              <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 100px;">Программа обучения VR</h2>
<div style="padding: 10px;">01</br>02</br>03</br>04</br>05</br></div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Addition**

Here is simple code snippet with position absolute if this is what you are looking for.

```css
.top-div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('https://photos.smugmug.com/Stock-images/Westward-Expansion-Photos/gettysburg-battlefield-photos/i-S8rSqgg/1/70e2c6c8/S/Gettysburg%20Battlefield%20Photos-S.jpg');
}
.bottom-div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: Orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 200px;
}
.overlay-holder {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  background: LightBlue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-holder">
  <div class="overlay">
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
    This text is in the overlay<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="top-div"></div>
<div class="bottom-div">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: As you see from design I have div with image and div with solid color and one block under those two divs.

Comment: Your image does not have to be div, it can be background-image of your download-section e.g.
background: url('path/to/your/image') #yoursolidcolor  no-repeat top center;